# Update function is disabled in Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

Im using MAGMI V 0.7.18 and i'm trying to import multiple images in Magento ver. 1.9.2.0 but MAGMI throws

```
"Update Disabled Zip library not available, Upgrade/Upload function are not enabled"
```

in the UPDATE section , I try to change the code in:

changed magmi/web/magmi_config_setup.php

changed magmi/web/magmi_upload.php
changed magmi/web/plugin_upload.php

but nothing happens, please Help me,

Comment: How can you be running Magmi 1.2 when the latest version is 0.7.23 ?

Comment: sorry for that mistake, i have changed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is generated by older Magmi versions if it can't find the ZipArchive php class. You need to install it in the proper way according to your server operating system. (e.g. apt-get install libphp-pclzip in Ubuntu 14.04)

Nonetheless I suggest you to keep your magmi always updated to the latest version.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have one doubt,Is there need image attribute processor for importing multiple images? if yes then, is it already in default magmi latest version ? or it will need to upload in magmi?

Comment: @venugopal In version 0.7.22 there is no such message in the codebase, Are you sure you have updated all the files?

Also for the images, the wiki clearly states that the image processor plugin is "is Mandatory to handle images", so yes, you will need to use it. It is included in magmi by default.

Comment: yes i have updated all files. downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ .first time site ask username and password  and i will give magmi/magmi then it shows after that when updating profile configuration again ask username and password and this time the username and password does not matching.

Comment: @venugopal The newest magmi versions wants administrative credentials (username and password of a store admin).